# How to get the x axis labels in flot?

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, cordova, flot, bar-chart

I am using Flot to create graphs.
This is my Code here [jsFiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/coderslay/WnC9B/)

```
function drawSeriesHook(plot, canvascontext, series) {
var ctx = canvascontext,
    plotOffset = plot.offset(),
    labelText = 'VALUE', // customise this text, maybe to series.label
    points = series.datapoints.points,
    ps = series.datapoints.pointsize,
    xaxis = series.xaxis,
    yaxis = series.yaxis,
    textWidth, textHeight, textX, textY;
// only draw label for top yellow series
if (series.color === '#F8C095') {
    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(plotOffset.left, plotOffset.top);

    ctx.lineWidth = series.bars.lineWidth;

    ctx.fillStyle = '#000'; // customise the colour here
    for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i += ps) {
        if (points[i] == null) continue;

        textWidth = ctx.measureText(labelText).width; // measure how wide the label will be
        textHeight = parseInt(ctx.font); // extract the font size from the context.font string
        textX = xaxis.p2c(points[i] + series.bars.barWidth / 2) - textWidth / 2;
        textY = yaxis.p2c(points[i + 1]) - textHeight / 2;
        ctx.fillText(labelText, textX, textY); // draw the label
    }
    ctx.restore();
}
}
```

1. In My drawseriesHook function i need to get the x axis labels like Data1,Data2,Data3,Data4
2. Is there any way to uniquely identify the last data item without using series.label & series.color.Currently i have identified it by modifying the series.color in the function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1.) Ok, I think you want to set `labelText` for each bar. Add the following line in the for-loop:

```
labelText = series.xaxis.ticks[i / ps].label;
```

Also see the [updated example](http://jsfiddle.net/WnC9B/2/).

2.) You can add own values to `data`, e.g. to mark the last one:

```
var data = [
    {
        label : 'Used',
        color : '#EF7816',
        data : [ [ 1, 85], [ 2, 50 ], [ 3, 18], [ 4, 8 ] ],
        last : false
    },
    ...
    {
        color : '#F8C095',
        data : [ [ 1, 12], [ 2, 10], [ 3, 3], [ 4, 2] ],
        last : true
    }
];
```

In your hook you can check the flag:

```
if (series.last) { ...
```

Also see the next [updated example](http://jsfiddle.net/WnC9B/3/).

Comment: this labels var will have all the ticks labels.How to individually get a label out of it?

Comment: @Coder_sLaY: you don't want all, you want only the current label?

Comment: yes exactly but when i put an alert(labels) then i get all the 4. I need only the first one.

Comment: I've added a possible answer for your 2nd question.